# How to create a method that counts how large a group is in an array?

Tags: java

I need some help making my Java method (getNumGroupsOfSize) work. It should tally how large an array "group" (consecutive elements that share the same value) is, and then print out how many other groups share that size. So for example, array `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7]` would print:

```
size 1=4

size 3=3
```

and then would stop running.

This is what I have so far:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayStats {
  int[] numArray;
  int number;

  public ArrayStats(int[] array) {
    setArray(array);
  }

  public void setArray(int[] array) {
    numArray = array;
  }

  public int getNumGroupsOfSize() {
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < numArray.length - 1; x++) {
    if (numArray[x] == numArray[x + 1]);
    cnt++;
    for (int y = 2; y <= 9; y++) {
      if (cnt == y)
        number = cnt;
      else if (cnt == 1)
        number = 1;
    }
  }
  return number;
}

public String toString() {
  return "size count" + " == " + getNumGroupsOfSize() + Arrays.toString(numArray);
}
}
```

I'm pretty sure my getNumGroupsOfSize is not coded correctly, but I'm not sure how to make it work. I would genuinely appreciate any help that can be offered. If you need any more information, don't hesitate to comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `getNumGroupsSize()` doesn't make much sense. For example how do you print out all the groups if you just store one number? I wrote the method new and it prints the numbers directly. You can also store them in an array if you want to.

```
public void getNumGroupsOfSize() {
    int cnt = 1;
    int currentNumber = numArray[0];
    for (int x = 0; x < numArray.length - 1; x++) {
        if (numArray[x] == numArray[x + 1]){
            cnt++;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(currentNumber + ": " + cnt);
            currentNumber=numArray[x+1];
            cnt=1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(currentNumber + ": " + cnt);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each encountered series, you have to count its size and update the information about how many series has this size.

So the `int number` field you are using is clearly not enough to achieve it as it persists only a very elementary information.

In your case, you need to have two associated information : for each series size, you want to know the number of series that have this size.

A `Map` object should do the job.
It would use as key the size of the series and as value the number of series that have this size.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> occurrenceBySeriesSize = new HashMap<>();
```

At each time an encountered series is finished, update the map with the new count :

```
 int serieSize = ...;

 Integer occurrences = occurrenceBySeriesSize.get(serieSize);
 if (occurrences == null){
    occurrences = 0;
 }
 occurrenceBySeriesSize.put(serieSize, ++occurrences);
```